# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable when overwriting old value

Tags: python, try-catch, nonetype

This is a simplification of my program, I have a hard time understanding why the error occurs and what the solution to it is.

```
def test(n=0):


 a = [];
 b = [];

 if n == 0:
  return a,b
 else:
  a.append(1);
  b.append(2);


for i in range(0,2):
 x,y = test(i)
```

x and y must have different values at each iteration, but since the function returns None at one point and then later it wants to overvwrite it , it will get crash with the error "TypeError" - is there a clean solution, despite using some kind of try - catch machnism?

The following code makes the program run, but it feels like misusing the try-catch mechanism of an earlier design error.

```
def test(n=0):


 a = [];
 b = [];

 if n == 0:
  return a,b
 else:
  a.append(1);
  b.append(2);


for i in range(0,2):
 try:
  x,y = test(i)
 except TypeError:
  continue;
```

Comment: `test` doesn't return anything

Comment: sry that was a copy&paste error

Comment: Also, you should drop the semi-colons, they don't serve any purpose in your example. In Python, they are used when you want to separate multiple instruction on the same line.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a stupid typo

Comment: @Qrom yeah I kinda learned that from C/C++ , hard to get rid of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function test has no return in such a case function automatically return None, while on return you are trying to put returned[0] to x and returned[1] to y. Where as returned is None which is not iterable.

Correct Code :

```
def test(n=0):


 a = [];
 b = [];

 if n == 0:
  return a,b
 else:
  a.append(1);
  b.append(2);

return a,b

for i in range(0,2):
 x,y = test(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do to me.

1) a and b are local arrays so they will never contain more than 1 element.
   Is this intended?

2) then your func test has no return in the else part so it will return None.
   you try to put None into x and y by iterating over None which cant be done and
   gives the error

Comment: thanks for your answer, it was a stupid mistake like by 2) , to 1) - this was just an example program like described, cause the orignal program is far too complex. I just want to delete this question, but since there are already anwers I am not allowed to do so ....